# θαυμάζω which meaning of “wonder” in John 3:7?

Tags: greek, john, jesus

θαυμάζω apparently means “wonder”, but which kind? In Plato’s talk about philosophy, it’s suggested by many to mean “puzzlement”. But in John 3:7, it’s suggested Jesus meant Nicodemus was struck with “awe” or “surprise”. I think the words awe and wonder are difficult concepts, so I’m looking for a more modern word and hoping that either puzzlement or surprise fits well enough. Can anyone offer help, please? I’m a bit lost on this.

[John 3:7 ABP](https://studybible.info/interlinear/John%203:7)

> You should not wonder that I said to you, ‘It is necessary for you to be born from above.’

Comment: I tried to edit to add a link, but I seem to have done it wrong, it isn’t working, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

In this context, it means “Don’t be puzzled!”

**Exaplanation**

When Jesus told Nicodemus that a man must be born again”, Nicodemus was **puzzled**, that is, he **wondered how** a man could be born again, hence his questions (John 3:4): “How can a man be born when he is old? Can he enter the second time into his mother’s womb and be born?”

In response, Jesus tells him, “Don’t be puzzled! [What I have described should not be foreign to you!”] Jesus asks Nicodemus, “You’re the teacher of Israel and don’t know these things?!”

In short, Nicodemus was puzzled, confused, how a man could be born again. Jesus tells him not to be puzzled, confused at the idea. Jesus describes Nicodemus as “the teacher of Israel”. Therefore, he should have been well acquainted with the concept from his knowledge of the Tanakh.

The meaning is indeed being born **again**. However, the confusion on Nicodemus’ part is that he misunderstood the second birth as being physical (cf. John 3:4), but it is spiritual (cf. John 3:6).

Comment: Thank you! This puts Nicodemus’ reaction into a better perspective for me. I’d rather he was confused and struggling to grasp the concept, rather than skeptically surprised at it and brushing it off. Especially with Jesus’ comment to him a bit further in about his unbelief, I was unsure which direction to go with this. I’d vote for your answer, but I don’t see a button to. Thanks for responding, it’s much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The operative verb in John 3:7 is θαυμάζω (thaumazo) which means (BDAG):

> 1. **to be extraordinarily impressed or disturbed by something**
>
> - (a) (intransitive) *wonder, marvel, be astonished* (the context determines whether in a good or bad sense), eg, Matt 8:10, 27, 9:33,
>   15:31, 22:22, 27:14, Mark 5:20, 15:5, Luke 1:63, 8:25, 11:14, 24:41,
>   John 5:20, 7:21, Acts 4:13, 13:12, 41, Rev 17:7, etc
> - (b) (transitive) *admire, wonder at, respect* (persons), eg, Luke 7:9, 24:12, John 5:28, Acts 7:31
>
> 2. **wonder, be amazed**, eg, Rev 17:8, 2 Thess 1:10 (?)

In all these shades of meaning, the very act of being amazed, marveling at something often involves an element of surprise and sometimes puzzlement, especially when one is astonished, because he says, "How can this be??" This, despite Jesus instruction (V7) for him NOT to be amazed.

Such wonder and puzzlement is certainly implied in the verb's use in John 3:7 - Nicodemus was puzzled about such things could be true.

Comment: Thank you! This puts an interesting spin on things. Extraordinarily impressed or disturbed, wow. I’d never thought of his reaction that way. Nicodemus must have had so many things going through his mind all at once in that moment. Perhaps including amazement, puzzlement, alarm, hesitancy, and a myriad of exploding contradictory t feelings and thoughts. If I could, I’d vote for you both. This is a “tie”, you both are fantastic! Thanks for responding, you have my gratitude!

Comment: I found the announcement that told me I can now, so I upvoted you both! I’m not tech-y, it took me til yesterday  to click the right thingy. Thanks!